# Do all Android devices support changing screen orientation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation, projector

I have a **problem** changing the **screen orientation** on a specific device( **mini-projector** which runs **Android 4.4.4**).
By **default** its screen orientation is **"landscape"** but **I want it on "portrait"**. I tried to **set the portrait mode from java**, programmatically, but also from the Manifest file, including **android:screenOrientation="landscape"** in the  tag. **The code works on a regular android tablet** and phones(Asus TF700 Android 4.2, Samsung Galaxy 10.1 Android 4.4.4, Samsung Galaxy S3 Android 4.4.4), it puts my activity in "portrait" mode, **but this doesn't happen with my mini-projector**.

Does anybody have an idea why it won't work on the mini-projector? Thank you!

Comment: then your mini projector doesnt have the sensor

Comment: Yes, indeed it doesn't have sensor, but I think this shouldn't be an impediment for setting the orientation mode. I don't want to change the orientation mode on device movement, I want to set it on start and to remain as it is.